# Is there a way for winui3 to display a pixel image with a size of 8*8

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I can do this in a WPF Application with these code:

```
<Image x:Name="myImage" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled" />
```

The corresponding effect is as follows
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed5MN.png

But to winui3

```
<Image Source="/Assets/steve.png" />
```

The corresponding effect is as follows, The image is enlarged many times and becomes blurry https://i.stack.imgur.com/q20Fv.png

And this is the raw image https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4QAb.png

So is there any way to keep the image of winui3 displayed in pixels?
I hope that the image in winui3 can get the display effect like in wpf

Comment: Do you want to keep the image at the original size, or use nearest neighbor "interpolation" when scaling? Note that the later tend to look crap for non integer scaling factors.

Comment: nearest neighbor "interpolation" when scaling @JonasH

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do it but none using XAML. The "classic" way is to use WinRT's [BitmapDecoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapdecoder) class and customize the way it works.

**Solution 1**

With this XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Click="Button_Click">click</Button>

    <Image x:Name="img" Grid.Row="1" Width="300" Height="300" />

</Grid>
```

And this code:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // create a BitmapDecoder
    var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(@"c:\somepath\q4QAb.png");
    using var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
    using var ras = stream.AsRandomAccessStream();
    var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(ras);

    // create a bitmap transform.
    // you'll have to call this with width & height corresponding to desired Image's with & height
    var transform = new BitmapTransform();
    transform.InterpolationMode = BitmapInterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
    transform.ScaledWidth = (uint)img.Width;
    transform.ScaledHeight = (uint)img.Height;

    // load the bitmap & bitmap source using transform
    using var bmp = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied, transform, ExifOrientationMode.RespectExifOrientation, ColorManagementMode.ColorManageToSRgb);
    var source = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
    await source.SetBitmapAsync(bmp);
    img.Source = source;
}
```

**Solution 2**

Here is another way, using [the Visual Layer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/composition/visual-layer) (aka: Direct Composition) which is not limited to UWP contrary to what the doc might say:

With this XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Click="Button_Click">click</Button>

    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Grid.Row="1" />

</Grid>
```

And this button handling code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // get visual layer's compositor
    var compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(canvas).Compositor;

    // create a surface brush, this is where we can use NearestNeighbor interoplation
    var brush = compositor.CreateSurfaceBrush();
    brush.BitmapInterpolationMode = CompositionBitmapInterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;

    // create a visual
    var imageVisual = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
    imageVisual.Brush = brush;

    // load the image
    var image = LoadedImageSurface.StartLoadFromUri(new Uri(@"c:\somepath\q4QAb.png"));
    brush.Surface = image;

    // set the visual size when the image has loaded
    image.LoadCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        // choose any size here
        imageVisual.Size = new System.Numerics.Vector2(300, 300);
        image.Dispose();
    };

    // add the visual as a child to canvas
    ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(canvas, imageVisual);
}
```

Note 1: in the solution 2 case, you don't have to use async/await code. Also you can resize the `imageVisual` visual at any time. Without any more context information, this is my preferred way.

Note 2: all UI/XAML namespaces *must* start by `Microsoft.UI.Xaml` to ensure you're using WinUI3 and *not* UWP.

Comment: Thank you so much! I used Solution 1 and it works perfectly in my program